# Flutter : Add 2 buttons, one on top of image and other on bottom of image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Add 2 buttons, one on top of image and other on bottom of image in flutter.
Please refer to the below image.

I want to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: add your code as well as expected result please.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Stack with image and ElevatedBUttons,
here's a sample :

```
Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/Image.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 10,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("Button 1"),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: 10,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("Button 2"),
                    ))
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example mostly derived from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583405/flutter-add-a-floating-action-button-to-an-image). You can add another `Positioned` widget inside the Stack's children and set it's `bottom` and `right` attributes to position a second button in the bottom right corner.

```dart
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/image1",
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          )),
      Positioned(
        right: 10.0,
        top: 10.0,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 30, // Adjust width and/or height of sized box to control button size
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```